# InvalidParameterValue: Invalid security group: can't attach the eks SGrule to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I am trying to provision RDS instance with private subnets using terraform template and my template looks like this
following attributes/restrictions while creating rds:

- Not publicly Accessible. Security group to be opened only for eks
  cluster, not public.

```
 cat modules/rds/rds.tf

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_instance" {
  allocated_storage      = 50
  identifier             = "rds-vaya"
  storage_type           = "gp2"
  engine                 = "mysql"
  engine_version         = "8.0.23"
  instance_class         = "db.t2.micro"
  db_name                = "vaya"
  username               = "admin"
  password               = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password.secret_string
  publicly_accessible    = false
  multi_az               = true
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.rdssubnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.eks-sg
  tags = {
    Name = "OpsyRDSServerInstance"
  }
}
```

```
 cat modules/rds/security.tf
#make rds subnet group
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rdssubnet" {
  name       = "database-subnet"
  subnet_ids = var.private_subnet_ids
}
```

```
cat modules/eks/security.tf
resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
  name   = "eks-sg-${var.env}"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  count                    = length(var.ingress_rule)
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = var.ingress_rule[count.index][0]
  to_port                  = var.ingress_rule[count.index][1]
  protocol                 = var.ingress_rule[count.index][2]
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.main.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.main.id
}
```

```
 cat modules/eks/output.tf
output "eks-sg" {
  value = aws_security_group_rule.ingress_rules.*.id
}
```

```
cat main.tf

module "eks_cluster" {
  source                        = "./modules/eks"
  eks_cluster_name              = var.eks_cluster_name
  vpc_id                        = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids                    = module.vpc.subnet_ids
  eks_cluster_role_arn          = module.iam.eks_cluster_role_arn
  eks_cluster_create_depends_on = module.iam.id
  instance_count                = var.instance_count
  instance_type                 = var.instance_type
  ingress_rule                  = var.ingress_rule
  env                           = var.env
}

module "rds" {
  source             = "./modules/rds"
  vpc_id             = module.vpc.vpc_id
  private_subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnet_ids
  eks-sg             = module.eks_cluster.eks-sg
  env                = var.env
}
```

Below is the terraform plan/apply:

```
  # module.rds.aws_db_instance.rds_instance will be created
  + resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_instance" {
      + address                               = (known after apply)
      + allocated_storage                     = 50
      + apply_immediately                     = (known after apply)
      + arn                                   = (known after apply)
      + auto_minor_version_upgrade            = true
      + availability_zone                     = (known after apply)
      + backup_retention_period               = (known after apply)
      + backup_window                         = (known after apply)
      + ca_cert_identifier                    = (known after apply)
      + character_set_name                    = (known after apply)
      + copy_tags_to_snapshot                 = false
      + db_name                               = "vaya"
      + db_subnet_group_name                  = "database-subnet"
      + delete_automated_backups              = true
      + endpoint                              = (known after apply)
      + engine                                = "mysql"
      + engine_version                        = "8.0.23"
      + engine_version_actual                 = (known after apply)
      + hosted_zone_id                        = (known after apply)
      + id                                    = (known after apply)
      + identifier                            = "rds-vaya"
      + identifier_prefix                     = (known after apply)
      + instance_class                        = "db.t2.micro"
      + kms_key_id                            = (known after apply)
      + latest_restorable_time                = (known after apply)
      + license_model                         = (known after apply)
      + maintenance_window                    = (known after apply)
      + monitoring_interval                   = 0
      + monitoring_role_arn                   = (known after apply)
      + multi_az                              = true
      + name                                  = (known after apply)
      + nchar_character_set_name              = (known after apply)
      + network_type                          = (known after apply)
      + option_group_name                     = (known after apply)
      + parameter_group_name                  = (known after apply)
      + password                              = (sensitive value)
      + performance_insights_enabled          = false
      + performance_insights_kms_key_id       = (known after apply)
      + performance_insights_retention_period = (known after apply)
      + port                                  = (known after apply)
      + publicly_accessible                   = false
      + replica_mode                          = (known after apply)
      + replicas                              = (known after apply)
      + resource_id                           = (known after apply)
      + skip_final_snapshot                   = false
      + snapshot_identifier                   = (known after apply)
      + status                                = (known after apply)
      + storage_type                          = "gp2"
      + tags                                  = {
          + "Name" = "OpsyRDSServerInstance"
        }
      + tags_all                              = {
          + "Name" = "OpsyRDSServerInstance"
        }
      + timezone                              = (known after apply)
      + username                              = "admin"
      + vpc_security_group_ids                = [
          + "sgrule-2349526507",
          + "sgrule-2500829248",
          + "sgrule-2855048482",
          + "sgrule-4188522375",
        ]
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + eks-sg = [
      + "sgrule-2500829248",
      + "sgrule-2349526507",
      + "sgrule-2855048482",
      + "sgrule-4188522375",
    ]

Do you want to perform these actions in workspace "dev"?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

module.rds.aws_db_instance.rds_instance: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating RDS DB Instance (rds-vaya): InvalidParameterValue: Invalid security group , groupId= sgrule-2349526507, sgrule-2500829248, sgrule-2855048482, sgrule-4188522375, groupName=.
│       status code: 400, request id: fb505df1-9202-4986-9d54-7e4af4fcbc91
│
│   with module.rds.aws_db_instance.rds_instance,
│   on modules/rds/rds.tf line 2, in resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_instance":
│    2: resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_instance" {
│
```

i've no idea what the problem and how to fix this issue.

Comment: Try to understand what you doing. It will help to understand what the problem is. Without understanding what is the point of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting the SG rule IDs while you want **SG IDs**. You need to use the attributes of the SG itself:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
  name   = "eks-sg-${var.env}"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
```

And the output should be (`modules/eks/output.tf`):

```
output "eks-sg" {
  value = aws_security_group.main.id
}
```